Refresh View Inside List Section SwitfUI
I have a SwiftUI List which I want to update once any field of the TransactionEntity record is updated. Here is the code:
struct HomeListView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: RecordViewModel
    var categoryName: String
    @State private var transactions: [TransactionEntity] = []
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(
                header: HStack {
                    Text(categoryModel.name)
                },
                content: {
                    ForEach(transactions) { transaction  in
                        let model = RecordModel(transaction: transaction)
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: RecordDetailsView(model: model),
                            label: {
                                HStack {
                                    Text(transaction.categoryName)
                                    Text(transaction.amount)
                                }
                            })
                    }
                }
            )
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            transactions = viewModel.fetchAllTransactions() ?? []
        })
    }
}

The RecordDetailsView page as follows:
struct RecordDetailsView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: RecordViewModel
    @State var model: RecordModel
    @State private var isAlertPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        let amountField = TextField("", text: model.amountValue)
            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)

        let saveButton = Button(
            action: {
                self.saveAction()
            },
            label: {
                Text("Save")
            }
        )
        Form {
            Section(header:
                        HStack {
                Image(systemName: "dollarsign")
                Text("Amount")
            }) {
                amountField
            }
            Section(header:
                        HStack {
                Image(systemName: "calendar")
                Text("Date")
            }) {
                DatePicker(
                    selection: model.valueDate,
                    in: ...Date(),
                    displayedComponents: [ .date, .hourAndMinute],
                    label: {
                        Text("")
                    })
                .datePickerStyle(.wheel)
            }
        }
    }

    func saveAction() {
        viewModel.saveTransactions(record: model)
        self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
}

The RecordViewModel & RecordModel as follows:
class RecordViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private let container: NSPersistentContainer
    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyExpense")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }
    func saveTransactions(record: RecordModel) {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "TransactionEntity", in: container.viewContext)!
        let transaction = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: container.viewContext) as! TransactionEntity
        transaction.setValue(record.amount, forKey: "amount")
        transaction.setValue(Date(), forKey: "createdAt")
        transaction.setValue(record.valueDate, forKey: "valueDate")
        do {
            try container.viewContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    func fetchAllTransactions() -> [TransactionEntity]? {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "TransactionEntity")
        do {
            return try container.viewContext.fetch(request)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not load. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            return nil
        }
    }
}


struct RecordModel: Encodable, Identifiable {
    var id: String = ""
    var objectID: NSManagedObjectID?
    var amount: Double = 0.0
    var valueDate: Date = Date()

    init(transaction: TransactionEntity) {
        self.id = String("\(transaction.objectID)")
        self.objectID = transaction.objectID
        self.amount = abs(transaction.amount)
        self.valueDate = transaction.valueDate ?? Date()

    }
}

Also the CoreData TransactionEntity+CoreDataProperties entity
extension TransactionEntity {
    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<TransactionEntity> {
        return NSFetchRequest<TransactionEntity>(entityName: "TransactionEntity")
    }

    @NSManaged public var amount: Double
    @NSManaged public var createdAt: Date?
    @NSManaged public var valueDate: Date?
}


Now the problem is after I modify the amount or date and go back to listing page the list doesn't update with latest amount or date of that particular record. Even onAppear I'm refreshing the transactions array.
So how to I force update the Section inside List View. Thanks in advance.

Please show a [mcve] - something I can copy and paste into a new Xcode project and reproduce the problem.

For ios17,
have a look at this link Managing model data in your app, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app.
For ios16, have a look at this link  Monitoring data. Just copy and paste the example code, as simple as that.
